# Is there any decentralized exchange with zero trading fees for ERC-20 tokens at the moment?

Tags: erc-20, exchanges, fees, decentralized-exchange

Is there any decentralized exchange with zero trading fees for ERC-20 tokens at the moment?

All fees except gas fees should be zero. I already tried Bancor and Kyber but, as far as I can tell, they both charge fees as far so I would like to find a zero fees exchange.

Vesa

Answer (score 1):

AirSwap is a decentralized, peer-to-peer trading network for Ethereum tokens with no trading fees. https://airswap.io

Comment: But there's slippage right? So that is almost worse and a fee of sorts.

Comment: [Your Twitter profile](https://twitter.com/jayks17) suggests that this is your own site. Recommending a site without disclosing your affiliation is a violation of the [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 1):

StellarX and ECX are two decentralized exchanges with no fee.

Answer (score 1):

If someone promote "no fees" for an ERC20 swap on a DEX, they are lying. It is not possible as it is running on the ETH network, which uses fees to run...

Using a DEX for a swap is interesting when it has enough liquidity to avoid big slippage. To attract this liquidity, DEX put some additional fees on swaps, fees they redistribute to the liquidity providers!

So you have ETH fees for running the swap smartcontract, + DEX fees.

Here is a little comparison of additional fees between the different DEX
You can see uniswap has 0.3% additional fees, and defiplaza.net only 0.1%
I like this defiplaza DEX as even its smartcontract is optimized for low fees swap.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Alfred. Note that your answer is technically incorrect, as the question was asking "zero trading fees". Gas fees are separate from trading fees. It is possible to create pools on Uniswap v3 with zero fees, but there is no incentive for anyone to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Radar Relay is a very popular DEX with [no fees at this time](https://support.radarrelay.com/en/support/solutions/articles/42000022033-what-are-your-fees-).

Comment: But it requires wrapping ETH right? That is not so hot. Any other option which is free but can handle actual ETH?

Comment: All decentralized exchanges, as they exist today, will need to use WETH. See my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62244/best-practices-on-handling-both-Ξ-and-tokens/62245#62245) for the reason why.

Comment: The use of wrapped ether is certainly not a technical requirement for  a decentralized exchange, but it's a popular choice that simplifies things.